# JAXB marshall wrapper object with generic list

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey, moxy

I'm implementing an Web Service using jersey and MOXy. The webservice will return the data as JSON result. I want to wrap some collections using the following wrapper class:

```
public class PaginationWrapper<T>
{
   private List<T> data;
   //other fields
   private...

   public List<T> getData()
   {
      return data;
   }

   public void setData(List<T> data)
   {
      this.data = data;
   }

   //other getter and setter
}
```

The problem is that with the generic no result will be returned. There is an exception raised:

```
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b):         org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred marshalling the object
Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-25007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: A descriptor for class packagereplaced.PaginationWrapper was not found in the project.  For JAXB, if the JAXBContext was bootstrapped using TypeMappingInfo[] you must     call a marshal method that accepts TypeMappingInfo as an input parameter.]
```

Replacing the generic type will fix that error but I dont want to create a wrapper for each data object I have. Cause I'm implementing the webservice with jersey and moxy I dont have access to the marshalling itself. I need an annotation based solution or something else which will work with jersey ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by replacing MOXy with jackson. Without any configuration the JSON marshalling worked out of the box.